Why does the Pilatus PC 7 Mk II Altimeter show a decrease in altitude (~around 20-40ft) during takeoff roll, but recovers to original before unstick?
PC7 Mk II is equipped with digital ADC, how come this anomaly in altimeter readings during takeoff roll? Also, the pitot tube is situated well away from the prop wash and it has two static ports on either side for static balancing.

It suggests that both ports are seeing some drop in pressure, possibly due to fuselage contours just ahead of them, and only when the propeller wash velocity is high relative to the free stream velocity. Just spitballing...

@Johnk, but if the Px is dropping, the Alti would show an increase in reading rather than decrease.

Oh yeah. In that case, the opposite lol.

What is the location of the static ports?

@AeroAndy, Static Ports located in aft fuselage (flushed with surface), well clear of wing trailing edge ~ 4-5 ft aft... on both sides (for static balancing)

Thanks, @tata_sumo. I wanted to post an answer but but… probably a hypothesis does not qualify. Very low speeds with high propeller rpm settings result in a corkscrew or spiraling rotation to the slipstream. “At high propeller speeds and low forward speed (as in takeoffs and approaches to power-on stalls), this spiraling rotation is very compact and exerts a strong sideward force on the aircraft’s vertical tail surface.” p. 5-31 of FAA-H-8083-25C

My guess is one of the static ports is picking up some total pressure component due to an unusually high sidewash angle at that aft location.

On Raptor, for example, using differential pressure (left-right) to determine sideslip angle was not calibratable beyond about 30 deg of sideslip angle. Point being, an average L-R pressure would have some error in it, also.

@AeroAndy, your guess agrees with the anomaly's vanishing when the airplane is rolling fast, stretching the spiral farther aft (from the airplane's point of view).
